# Cinnamon being a complete mess on Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, cinnamon

After installing Cinnamon the desktop icons on cinnmaon have black text where i want white and the windows are appearing as follows:[image: Windows]

And for the desktop, it is appearing like this,
[image: Desktop]

How do i remove the big black things in windows and change icon the icon text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer finally! Installing Gnome tweak tool and enabling universal dark theme solves the problem.